# VB + DevExpress Button is not firing click event

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

My button doesn't fire click event

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnLancar" runat="server" Text="Lançar" AutoPostBack="true" />
 Protected Sub btnLancar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
                                                            Handles btnLancar.Click    

 End Sub
```

Comment: how do you know the event is not firing?

Comment: It does not fall in break point

Comment: Can you check after adding some code to the method, maybe change the button text or something?

Comment: The Same. still not firing

Comment: if you double click on the button in form designer, does it come to this function?

Comment: Yes, and if I change the button for a linkbutton it works

Comment: Do you have any validation on the page that may be failing?

Comment: All Validation are okay, and still blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASPxButton element needs to have the OnClick attribute set.

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnLancar" runat="server" Text="Lançar" AutoPostBack="true" OnClick="btnLancar_Click" />
```

Comment: using this signature ?
Protected Sub btnok_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnok.Click

Comment: I don't know if helps, But I'm using a Validation Sumary 
      <dx:ASPxValidationSummary ID="vldUnico" runat="server" RenderMode="BulletedList" />

Comment: That's the correct signature for VB.Net.  ClickHandler(object, EventArgs).  Adding the OnClick attribute to the button in the ASPX page should be enough to fire the event.  You can set a breakpoint in it like you did before to confirm.  If it still isn't called then try commenting out the ASPxValidationSummary and try again to see if that's a second issue that we need to look at.

Comment: Did this answer work for you?  If so, would you please accept it so that others can find it?  If not, please comment so I or someone else can help more.

Comment: Still not working... I take of all validation and still not working